# RHive: Only simple `select` works?

Tags: r, hadoop

I am running RHive (https://github.com/nexr/RHive) with Hadoop 2.2.0.2.0.6.0-101 on CentOS (**Linux** 2.6.32-431.5.1.el6.x86_64)

RHive can do basic`select` query:

> rhive.query("select * from simple")

And RHive fails to perform queries with condition. For example:

> rhive.query("select * from simple order by rating")

```
Error: java.sql.SQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
```

> rhive.query("select * from simple where name == 'Bond'")

```
 Error: java.sql.SQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
```

Any way to make it support Hive QL in full?

Thanks!

Comment: I just ran into the same issue now. Have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

While connecting to RHive, provide the Hive user's username and password, or credentials of any HDFS user as below:

```
rhive.connect(host="IP of Hive server", port=10000, hiveServer2=TRUE, user="hive",
              password="")
```